# sails.js Array sorting in waterline mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, waterline

> The array is

```
var array=["rahul","imran","Adi","samrat","Adi"];
```

> i want to sort this array and do a query like

var sortedArray= array.distinct(sort:'ASC');

> How can i do this any solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5)

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var a = ['zebra', 'cat', 'zebra', 'giraffe'];

out.log(_.uniqBy(_.sortBy(a))); // returns [ 'cat', 'giraffe', 'zebra' ]
```